# Dynamically reload log4j.properties for grails application running in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, logging, log4j

I have a grails application, deployed to tomcat, that is using log4j.  I would like to be able to update /webapps/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties in tomcat, and then have the application dynamically pickup the changes without requiring a restart.  I haven't had any luck finding a good way to do this.  What I have figured out is:

I can retrieve a file as a stream:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties")
```

Unfortunately this is the class loaded during startup, and I'm not sure if/how I can force it to update from the actual file.  If that worked I could read each property and use:

```
Logger.rootLogger.loggerRepository.getLogger(<key>).level = <new log level>
```

I've seen things about `LogManager.resetConfiguration()` but that doesn't seem to help either.

Also, this is how I setup log4j in `resources.groovy`

```
beans = {
    // Setting up external configuration for log4j
    log4jConfigurer(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
        targetClass = "org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"
        targetMethod = "initLogging"
        arguments = ["classpath:log4j.properties"]
    }
}
```

I'm not interested in using the `configureAndWatch` approach as I've read about its vulnerabilities.

I see that there are XML and JSON properties you can use for log4j, and I'm just using a plain *.properties file, and I'm not sure if that is part of the problem.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the [external-config-reload plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload) any help?  -- I've never used it though, so this is more of a question rather than an endorsement ;-)

Comment: I had tried using this, but the grails.plugins.reloadConfig.interval property didn't seem to refresh the properties when expected. Although I admit that it's very possible I had something else misconfigured with the plugin.

Comment: Is this with the properties inside the webapp folder?  Have you tried putting the properties file outside of the webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what I did to get around this issue, it required setUseCaches(false), to make sure that cached versions of a file (from the classloader) were not used.

```
def fileInputStream = null
// The method below is used to ensure that the file is read from disk every time, rather than using the previously loaded file from the ClassLoader
def classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
def resource = classLoader.getResource("log4j.properties")
def connection = resource.openConnection()
connection.setUseCaches(false)
// Warning: do not read or log the fileInputStream, because it will close the connection
fileInputStream = (FileInputStream)connection.getInputStream().in
// Use the Properties object to prevent errors on comments (#)
def props = new Properties()
props.load(fileInputStream)
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)
```

Then I can reference logger properties using:

```
config.log4j.logger.each {
    Logger.rootLogger.loggerRepository.getLogger(it.key).level = Level.toLevel(it.value)
}
```

You can also make checks to see what the existing log levels are and provide output to state which logging has actually changed.